# Substring from a string in bash using scripting language

Tags: bash, shell

How can we fetch a substring from a string in bash using scripting language?

Example:

```
fullstring="mnuLOCNMOD.URL = javascript:parent.doC...something"
```

The substring I want is everything before ".URL" in the full string.

Answer (score 5):

With [*Parameter Expansion*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion), you can do:

```
fullstring="mnuLOCNMOD.URL = javascript:parent.doC...something"
echo ${fullstring%\.URL*}
```

prints:

```
mnuLOCNMOD
```

Comment: I like this solution.

Comment: how shall I use this in .sh file

Comment: @shraddhaagrawal If you mean, how to assign it then, you can do: `substring=${fullstring%\.URL*}`

Comment: it is not working
also with
substring=`echo ${fullstring%\.URL*}`
it is not working in my .sh file otherwise it is working in bash shell

Comment: substring=${fullstring%\.URL*} this is not working sir
and I used echo ${fullstring%\.URL*} with a ` (a charater looks simillar to single quotes it is not getting pprinted here)

Comment: @shraddhaagrawal: This answer _should_ be POSIX-compliant - see [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). What shell are you using where it doesn't work? As an aside: note that you specifically asked for a `bash` solution.

Comment: Please double-quote the variable reference to promote good habits. While `\.` to produce a _literal_ `.` does work in this case, it is not _necessary_ and can mislead people to think that `.` is special in a parameter expansion, which it isn't.
The suffix to strip is a _pattern_, not a regex; thus: `echo "${fullstring%.URL*}"` will do. In Bash, the conceptually clearest formulation would be to selectively single-quote the parts to be taken literally: `echo "${fullstring%'.URL'*}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ fullstring="mnuLOCNMOD.URL = javascript:parent.doC...something"
$ sed -r 's/^(.*)\.URL.*$/\1/g' <<< "$fullstring"
mnuLOCNMOD
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`:

```
echo "mnuLOCNMOD.URL = javas" | grep -oP '\w+(?=\.URL)'
```

and assign the result to a string. I used a positive lookahead (`?=regex`) because it's a zero length assertion, meaning that it'll be matched but won't be displayed.

Run `grep --help` to find out what `o` and `P` flags stand for.

Comment: Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: -o and P are not supported

Comment: @shraddhaagrawal are not supported where?

Comment: @shraddhaagrawal Are you on a Solaris system?

Answer (score 0):

```
fullstring="mnuLOCNMOD.URL = javascript:parent.doC...something"
menuID=`echo $fullstring | cut -f 1 -d '.'`
```

here I used dot as a separator
this works in .sh files

Comment: Yes, this is POSIX-compliant, but it is also far less restrictive than what you asked for; if you really wanted to match before `.URL` specifically (and ignore other `.` instances), this would not work. If you only care about the _first_ `.`, whatever it is followed by, you should have phrased your question like that.

Answer (score 0):

[Parameter Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35719894/3789550) is the way to go.

If you are interested in a simple `grep`:

```
% fullstring="mnuLOCNMOD.URL = javascript:parent.doC...something"

% grep -o '^[^.]*' <<<"$fullstring"
mnuLOCNMOD
```

Answer (score 0):

To offer yet another alternative: Bash's regular-expression matching operator, `=~`:

```
fullstring="mnuLOCNMOD.URL = javascript:parent.doC...something"
echo "$([[ $fullstring =~ ^(.*)'.URL' ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")"
```

Note how the (one and only) capture group (`(.*)`) is reported through element `1` of the special `"${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"` array variable.

While in this case [l3x's parameter expansion solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35719894/45375) is simpler, `=~` generally offers more flexibility.

---

`awk` offers an easy solution as well:

```
echo "$(awk -F'\\.URL' '{ print $1 }' <<<"$fullstring")"
```